# Looking for a simple javascript HTML GUI builder that I can embed into my website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface

I have an advertising website and I'm looking for a snippet or web app that would let my users easily build their own custom ads. It needs to have a simple interface and should have simple objects to insert, such as images, divs, and text with font options.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called "WYSIWYG editors". Most famous ones: TinyMCE and CKEditor.

http://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/tinymce-vs-ckeditor

Comment: I'm looking for something that is more drag and drop

Answer (score 0):

[SPABuilder](http://spabuilder.appspot.com/) or [Ext Gui Builder](http://tof2k.com/ext/formbuilder/), the latter looking considerably better. Note that they introduce their own set of widgets, which is a must if you want this type of application. There is still a learning curve in these, but I can't see how you could eliminate this without a brain-to-computer interface or magic.

So if you want an arbitrary set of widgets you might need to code up something yourself, although you might have some luck restyling elements rendered by the above tools.